# Android Studio. Cannot launch app from device

Tags: android, mobile, development-environment

I am trying launch app from device (Meizu 2m mini) in Android Studio, but it does not see this usb connection. I customize connection to computer in settings device, android studio has installed google usb. 
Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the app using Android Studio or is your device not getting recognized? Isn't clear.

Comment: Did you try to enable debugging mode for developer option?

Comment: "Android studio does not see this usb connection". Computer getting recognize of connection with device. I'm install my app on emulator, but I can not launch project with usb connection.
Yes, I change setting for developers. Turn on debugging

Answer (score 0):

You may need to download a USB driver for your phone. I would google "Meizu 2m mini driver" and try again after downloading the correct driver.

Comment: I trying connect my phone across PdaNet Desktop. In device manager I see device as Android Phone, but then I trying launch in cmd command "adb device" - but it does not see my device.

Comment: Also I trying install driver across device manager, but for installing require driver and it does not exist in package (drivers for meizu from official site and forums). May be it exist, but device manager said: "I'm not find drivers". 
I read info on https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver, but device Meizu does not exist in this list